# wpf datagrid apply cell template after first two cells or column index greater than 1 in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created cell template, Inside cell template have added data template with data type double .  I want to apply cell template or data template after first two columns of the data grid

how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gridHolesList.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (gridHolesList.Columns[i].FieldName == "#" || gridHolesList.Columns[i].FieldName == "Name")
    {
        continue;
    }
    string cellTemplate = @"
    <DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
                 xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
                  xmlns:dxe=""http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"">
       <dxe:TextEdit x:Name=""PART_Editor""
                   EditValue=""{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Mode=OneWayToSource , Path=EditValue,
                                                                          Converter={StaticResource FeetInchesInputConverter} , 
                                                                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}""
                     Style=""{StaticResource FeetInchesRegualarExpression}"" 
  />

 </DataTemplate>";

    gridHolesList.Columns[i].CellTemplate = XamlReader.Parse(cellTemplate) as DataTemplate;
    gridHolesList.Columns[i].SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector to select template based on some condition..

a quick search got me this [link](https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/apply-conditional-data-template-in-data-grid/)

see if its any good to you.

Comment: I am trying out this link but in my case columns are auto-generated , I do not have any column definitions , In above link every column  definition is give separate datatemplate

Comment: DataGrid provides an event called AutoGeneratingColumn. You can jump into this event to mend it, some thing like this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43525/WPF-DataGrid-Using-DataTemplates-for-auto-generate)

Comment: Although I personally Hate autoGenerated columns, can you not define the first few that you want to manipulate ?

Comment: Thanks Muds , I gave data-template to only specific columns looping over index , In AutogenerateColumns event of datagrid it worked for me